# 64-bit ArrayList for Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, indexing, 64-bit

Is there a class or a library which function just like ArrayList class in Java, but it use 64-bit index (`long`) and size?

Don't say that it is useless or not needed. 10 years ago, people don't need 4GB of memory. Nowadays, laptops are having 8GB or even 16GB of memory. So `int` is no longer adequate.

Comment: FWIW, actual arrays are limited to 2G entries by language definition, so any such ArrayList could not be based on a single array.

Comment: ArrayList, [at least for now](https://openjdk.org/projects/valhalla/), can only contain objects. That means arraylist itself contains a sequence of pointers and they are likely to be 64-bit sized. The objects those things are pointing at then comprise generally at least 192 bits, unless your arraylist contains lots of `null` or the same reference repeated a lot. So, even the smallest one that requires 64-bit index (2^31 entries), you're looking at 2GB*32 = 64GB worth of RAM. __Which laptops still do not have__. So, I'll tell you: What you want? IS USELESS. For now. Give it a few years.

Comment: A less-useless thing would be, specifically, a 'growable/shrinable list of bytes/floats/ints specifically', and those _do exist_.. I think. I've done some quick web searches but I can't find it nor can I recollect the name of what I'm vaguely remembering.

Comment: @rzwitserloot You might be thinking of something like Android's [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray).